# Springboot : How to use string type attribute in postgres Jsonb column

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jsonb

I am trying to use string type attribute in Entity in springboot and was trying to save it using jpa repository call "repository.save()" for postgres Jsonb column.

But getting error:

> jsonb but expression is of type character varying  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Any Idea how to solve this.

*Tried attribute converters and mapper.writeAsByte etc*

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution after lot of searching, I use

```
@ColumnTransformer(write = "?::jsonb")
```

and this did the magic.

What this does is it adds a cast to jsonb to the attribute generated sql query